# Word for passing a vehicle going the other way

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Is there another word besides "pass" that more accurately specifies the act of two vehicles going past each other in opposite directions, as opposed to overtaking a vehicle going the same direction?

I want to be able unambiguously to explain right-of-way to bicyclists who insist I move to the far edge when I'm walking against the traffic.

Comment: If you want to unambiguously explain your right of way to bicyclists, just do what Dustin Hoffman did in *Midnight Cowboy*: slam your hand on the front of their vehicle and yell, "Hey! I'm walkin' here!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are referring to the act of passing *oncoming* traffic.

> - The bicyclist shall pass oncoming traffic on the far right.
> - The car almost hit oncoming traffic by moving too close to the center line.